# Align cards with dynamic height and width to bootstrap 3.3.6?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.6 cards to show few details to the user. my problem is cards not arranged properly with same height and width. I need to align the cards properly with same height and width. I used display:flex and flex-wrap: wrap CSS but it's not aligned properly. I also tried with display:inline-block it didn't work. I want cards to be aligned properly with same height and width horizontally.

Any help will be appreciated, checkout my below code.

I used display:flex and flex-wrap: wrap CSS but it's not aligned properly. I also tried with display:inline-block it didn't work.

```
styles.css
.card {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
    top:auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    object-fit: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
 
.card-header {
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

.card-header > span {
    font-size: 18px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.cardImage {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px 30px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.card-text {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.card > hr {
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.card-footer {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 93%;
}

.card-footer > button {
    background-color: black;
    object-fit: cover;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.card-footer > button > span {
    color: white;
}
 
myapp.cshtml
 
@using (Html.BeginForm("myapplication", "app"))
{
    foreach (var item in Model.myapplication)
    {
        var divAppIdAdd = "NewAddFav" + item.Id.ToString();
        var divAppIdRemove = "RemoveFavourites" + item.Id.ToString();
        var divTableId = "MenuTable" + item.Id.ToString();
        <div class="card">
            <div>
                <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image)" alt="" class="cardImage" />
            </div>
            <div class="card-header">
                <span>@item.Name</span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="@item.Url" target="_blank">
                                        <img src="/img/HomeButton.png" title="Go to site" class="LinkToSite">
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <img id="@divAppIdAdd" src="~/img/FavoriteIcon.svg" title="Add to Favourites"
                                         class="AddFav" onclick="fnAddApp(@item.Id.ToString()); return false;">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <img id="@divAppIdRemove" src="~/img/DeleteIcon.png" title="Remove Favourites"
                                         class="RemoveFav" onclick="fnRemoveMyApp(@item.Id.ToString());  return false;">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 card-text">
                <p>@item.Description</p>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="col-12 card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-block">
                    <span>View more...</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

The above code dynamically creates card based on the items present in database. Below is the image representation of my problem
[image: Cards Image]